# CloudBlockBlob.DownloadTextAsync returns invalid text

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure blob storage to store a JSON file and in my code I download it using the C# APIs.

When I download the contents of the text file and attempt to Deserialize it using JsonConvert, I get an error (the Visual Studio JSON visualizer also shows an error for the text).  However, if I copy the text and paste into JSONLint.com it appears fine.  Also, If I manually download the file from Azure Storage and read the file in code, it deserializes just fine.  Any ideas why I am getting invalid data when I download using the C# APIs?

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(folderAndFileName);
var text =  await blob.DownloadTextAsync();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
// Exception: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

Note: I am uploading the file via Powershell:

```
$blobProperties = @{"ContentType" = "application/json"};
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -File  $LocalFilePath -Blob $RemoteBlobName -BlobType "Block" -Properties $blobProperties
```

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. Can you please tell the version of storage client library you're using? Also, will it be possible for you to share the JSON file you uploaded? I would like to give it a try using that file.

Answer (score 3):

After further investigation, I found that the downloaded file has an extra Unicode formatting character at the start.  I added the following code to just check for special characters at the beginning and remove them...

```
var startIndex = 0;
while (char.GetUnicodeCategory(text, startIndex) == UnicodeCategory.Format)
{
     startIndex++;
}
text = text.Substring(startIndex, text.Length - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code. It seems that this issue is not about your code. The following is my tested result with your code:

[image]

**Entity:**

```html
    public class People
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address")]
        public string  Address { get; set; }
    }
```

**Json File:**

```html
{
  "name": "jambor",
  "address": "us"
}
```

As Gaurav Mantri said, I would suggest you check your [storage library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/). The version of my Azure storage library is 7.2.1. Please also set breakpoint at the code `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);`. Then check the value of text. It may help you to find out the issue.